# Where do I find magento 2 cart buttons action?

Tags: magento2, cart

I'm using magento 2 , and I need to find the cart close button and go to checkout button actions , and edit it , but I can't find the right files for that, does anyone knows where to find them ?

Comment: are you talking about minicart?

Comment: yes is about minicart !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to file path,    vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

check below part for close button html like,

```
<button type="button" id="btn-minicart-close" class="action close" data-action="close" data-bind="attr: { title: $t('Close') }" title="Close">
        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Close' --><span>Close</span><!-- /ko --></span>
    </button>
```

For close button html in minicart above display we can find `data-action="close"` from js file.

```
closeSidebar: function() {
            var minicart = $('[data-block="minicart"]');
            minicart.on('click', '[data-action="close"]', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                minicart.find('[data-role="dropdownDialog"]').dropdownDialog("close");
            });
            return true;
        }
```

Here list of url for checkout, update button, login url, remove button

```
 "url": {
            "checkout": window.checkout.checkoutUrl,
            "update": window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
            "remove": window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
            "loginUrl": window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
            "isRedirectRequired": window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
        },
        "button": {
            "checkout": "#top-cart-btn-checkout",
            "remove": "#mini-cart a.action.delete",
            "close": "#btn-minicart-close"
        }
```

Comment: This is the file I was looking for , thank you for your time @Rakesh !

Comment: if any issue then tell me

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel:

For Front End:

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

Then clean your cache by running `php bin/magento cache:clean` from your root folder.

Then you can see template path hint will be enable and then you can find any files which you want to edit.

Comment: I know how to get into the /home/aspirede/public_html/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/yume/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml
file , my problem is I can't find where the actions are written.. the the functions are properly written..